# Shared dataset or RDD in concurrent spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark

I have 4 spark jobs running concurrently. Is it possible for these jobs to share and `RDD` or a `Dataset`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with the existing spark API's.
Although there are few implementations to address this particular kind of usecase.

Refer this [link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Share-1-RDD-between-2-Spark-applications-memory-persistence/m-p/31408#M1086)

Apache Ignite is yet another project which is memory-centric distributed store which might be doing things like sharing RDD's between jobs. 
https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that fits your case will be apache ignite which will have the similar implementation to the apache spark and easy to understand as all the API available on the javardd, javapairrdd, dataframe/dataset are available on that igniterdd.

https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd#section-running-sql-queries-against-ignite-cache

At the end you can find the examples both in scala and java.